# Linq - what locale/collation it uses to compare objects?

Tags: linq, .net-3.5

When I call a Linq (not Linq-for-SQL, just simple in-memory Linq) - what locale it uses to compare objects, and how can I affect it?

E.g.

```
string[] a = { "a", "b", ... };
string max = a.Max();
```

What locale is used here - current, invariant? How can I affect it? 
The comparision seems to be case-insensitive, what if I want to find case-sensitive max?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses the implementation of `IComparable<string>` in string.

You could fairly easily write your own version of Max which *does* take an `IComparer<T>` for comparisons - I'm very surprised there isn't one already. Alternatively, you could use Aggregate in a somewhat cumbersome way to accomplish the same result.

Comment: what overload? I don't see any overload of max that takes IComparer<>:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.max.aspx

Comment: I do apologise - you're absolutely right. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Yes, the Aggregate is good choice:

max = files.Aggregate((a, b) => StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Compare(a, b) < 0 ? b : a);

Answer (score 0):

I decided to take a deeper look on what happening.

Max method uses Comparer class to compare items. Comparer class in turn uses GenericComparer.Compare method. This method calls String.CompareTo method. CompareTo uses following code:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.Compare(this, strB, CompareOptions.None);
```

That said, you can affect behavior of Max method by changing

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
```

If it's unacceptable, you have to roll out your own version of Max as Jon suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Posting my code based on Jon's suggestion:

```
static T Max<T>(this IEnumerable<T> coll, IComparer<T> comp)
{
    return coll.Aggregate((a, b) => comp.Compare(a, b) < 0 ? b : a);
}
```

It can be used as

```
string max = coll.Max(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```